# ionic 3 angular ion-slide vertical align top

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 `ion-slides` and `ion-slide`. The issue I am facing is the contents are in the center and I want it to be top aligned. Code looks like:

```
<ion-content padding>

    <ion-slides pager>
      <ion-slide style="vertical-align:top">
          <ion-card padding>
           <ion-card-header class="ha-card-header">About you</ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-label>Family Size&nbsp;<ion-badge>{{energyProfile.familySize}}</ion-badge></ion-label>
                    <ion-item no-padding>
                        <ion-range [(ngModel)]="energyProfile.familySize" min="0" max="10" step="2">
                          <ion-icon range-left small name="person"></ion-icon>
                          <ion-icon range-right name="people"></ion-icon>
                        </ion-range>
                    </ion-item>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
      </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
<ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you make plunker out of this?

Comment: Can you try it?:

    <ion-slide style="height: 100vh;display: block;vertical-align: initial;">

Comment: Check out [`centeredSlides`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#input-properties), cant try it myself right now but it looks like it does what you want.

Comment: @robbannn this should work based on documentation but doesnt

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a css rule to do that:

```
ion-slide.swiper-slide {
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

The default is `align-items: center;`.

**EDIT**:

From [@Ryan Coolwebs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2006447/ryan-coolwebs) comments:

> You may also find (on some occasions) that you also will now need to
>   adjust the pagination component as it will be under the
>   '.swiper-wrapper' with significant whitespace (i.e placing the
>   `ion-slides` component within col layout).
>
> A reasonable solution is to inset the pagination by assigning this
>   css:
>
> ```
> ion-slides.slides {
>   height: auto;
> }
>
> .swiper-pagination {
>   bottom: 0px;
> }
> ```
>
> Then adjust the transparency settings and colors of pagination system.

Comment: Looks like if you use this css override, you will also need to adjust the 'pager' as well (if being used).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RyanCoolwebs. Is there a specific css rule that you should use to adjust the pager? Feel free to edit the answer and add it if you want :)

Comment: @sebaferreras, I made some edits in your answer to include additional information about the pager.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs Hmm, seems like that edit was rejected by some other StackOverflow reviewers. I'll take a look at it now and will add it to the answer :)

Comment: Hey either way I don’t really care what they think, I was just trying to help out - there is no particular one solution to the issue. Cheers